# when echo do not display a blank field

Tags: php

I would like to not display any blank fields when I echo the results.

[image: Blank Fields display, I would like to remove them from display]

[image: Blank Fields display, I would like to remove them from display]

```
<textarea name="Urgent-Important" id="u_i" style="height: 400px; resize: none;" maxlength="10000" placeholder="" data-hint="">
<?php 
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

    echo "\r";
    echo $row1 ['u_i'] ; 
    echo "\r"; 

} 
mysqli_free_result($data);
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: What generates this? What about updating query to not pull empty rows? `where u_i <> ''` or `where u_i is not null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(! empty($row1['u_i']) ) echo "\r" . $row1['u_i'] . "\r";
```